# Minor markdown-mode for comments

Tags: minor-mode, markdown-mode

I like to use the markdown-mode for READMEs.

And I would like to use the markdown-mode as a minor-mode for comments in other major-modes like sh-mode. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You seem to be confused about major and minor modes. markdown-mode is a major mode of which only one is active at a time. Minor modes serve a completely different purpose, enhancing a major mode in a possibly unrelated way. What you're looking for is a multi-mode combining major modes...

Comment: @wasamasa One could also interpret the question as: Is there a minor mode that **acts like** `markdown-mode` in comments (maybe restricted to buffers having major-modes derived from `prog-mode`). In that case I would say it is an interesting question.

Comment: @Tobias That I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A `markdown-minor-mode` would be nice, yes.  I currently have some ad-hoc code to highlight comments assuming markdown syntax for my [typer-mode](https://gitlab.com/monnier/typer/blob/master/emacs/typer-mode.el).  It only supports a limited subset of markdown and only performs highlighting, but it shouldn't be difficult to extract it into its own `markdown-minor-mode` (probably easier than to try and adapt the code from `markdown-mode` major mode).